# How to get download url for a Image from Firebase Storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an image to firebase storage after that I am trying to get the download url of image but it's not working. Below is the code :

```
const response = await fetch(selectedImage.uri);
const file = await response.blob();

const storageRef = ref(storage, `profile/${currentUser.email}`);
uploadBytes(storageRef, file).then( (snapshot) => {
  console.log('uploaded');
  getDownloadURL(storage).then( url => console.log(url)); // tried this outside of then block as well
});
```

the file is uploaded and accessible through console but getDownloadURL throws error :

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: ref._throwIfRoot is not a function. (In 'ref._throwIfRoot('getDownloadURL')', 'ref._throwIfRoot' is undefined)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing `storage` to `getDownloadURL()`, pass `snapshot.ref`.

```js
const response = await fetch(selectedImage.uri);
const file = await response.blob();

const storageRef = ref(storage, `profile/${currentUser.email}`);
uploadBytes(storageRef, file).then( (snapshot) => {
  console.log('uploaded');
  getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then( url => console.log(url));
});
```